# Selected in select option (PHP)

Tags: php, html, laravel, select

I've some pb with a piece of code in PHP Laravel.

```
<select id="month-select">
   <option value="0">select month</option>
      @for ($i =0; $i <=12; $i++)
   <option value="{{today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m")}}">{{today()->subMonth($i)-format("Y-m")}}</option>
      @endfor
</select>
```

I'd like to add a selected and verify if my selected date is the same as the date in the parameter (*$date*).

I thought of something like this:

```
<option value="{{today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m")}}"{{(today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m")) && (!is_null(today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m"))) == $date ? 'selected':''}}>{{today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m")}}</option>
```

It is not optimised yet, and it doesn't work. Only the last value is selected. What's wrong?

Comment: Might be the missing space in `'selected'`. Make sure (outside of the `<option>`) that your condition is actually true. (Comparing `!is_null(...` to a date looks suspicious)

Comment: Having no space would result in something like `<option value="2021-10-19"selected...` - not sure how browsers handle that missing space

Comment: Can you show value of `$date` ?

Comment: $date=is_null($date)? Carbon::now():Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m', $date);

Comment: What is *"pb"?*

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare? It looks like you're taking the return from `is_null` – which is a boolean – and (loosely) comparing it to `$date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="month-select">
    <option value="0">select month</option>
    @for ($i =0; $i <= 12; $i++)
       <option value="{{today()->subMonth($i)->format('Y-m')}}"
         {{today()->subMonth($i)->eq($date) ? 'selected': ''}}>
         {{today()->subMonth($i)->format("Y-m")}}
       </option>
   @endfor
</select>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was wrong with the original code, what did you change, and why does it work? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69958761/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).